Connect DBeaver with Redshift through VPN
Currently I'm facing this problem, I have my AWS Redshift cluster with a sample dataset and I want to test different ways to share my data. I tried to connect my cluster with Dbeaver but always I got the error
Connection attempt time out.
In my cluster configuration I turned off the "Publicity Accessible" checkbox

Because I cannot attach the Internet Gateway in my VPC.
I configure my security group with All traffic in my VPN and in itself (the same security group) but I cannot connect Dbeaver.

Can someone help me?

With Redshift public accessibility off your cluster does not have an address that can be reached from the internet.  You need some proxy, gateway, or something that will route traffic to and from your cluster to the internet.
Changing the security rules of the VPC doesn't provide a route, it just allows  the traffic to flow on the VPC.
Since you cannot have a gateway on your VPC I'd suggest you look into setting up an SSH jumpbox.  This is an EC2 instance that will authenticate a connection and once done will proxy traffic to and from your Redshift cluster.    See: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/private-redshift-cluster-local-machine
